# Calling static files on express js not working

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express js app under directory **/api** and default root in **index.js** file.

I have second file called **data.js** under directory called **routes**

the **data.js** contain route **'/api/data/sickers'** and it s working fine.

**data.js** uses a method that is inside a directory called **Modules** in file called **connection**

inside **data.js** where I call the method I call it using the following :

```
var con = require('../Modules/connection.js');
```

I have tried to use app.use(path.join(_dirname,'Modules')); in index but not working .

the arrchitect of directories like the following :

```
-api

----index.js                  (default route '/api')

----routes
           -- data.js         (route : '/api/data/sickers' / method called to work here)
----Modules
           -- connection.js   (the method is here)
```

Comment: try this `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/Modules')));`

Comment: Are you asking about loading modules with `require()` when your server starts up?  Or are you asking about serving static files from your server to the client when the client requests them?  I'm confused about what this question means.

Comment: thanks for your comments , I m just trying to use some methods that exist in a file inside an other one that exist in other directory , at localhost it s working when using '../Modules/connection' but on server it's not working and return error.